# Nodejs function call issue in calling API

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

Hi I am using Nodejs library Soap to build a client

```
var soap = require('soap');
  var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
  var args = {name: 'value'};
  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      client.us.tx(args, function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

Issue is a function name is like us.tx from wsdl. When I use it I get wrong function message. 
Please let me know how I can call this function Thanks

Comment: What about `client['us.tx'](args, ...);`?

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: can you provide that wsdl you use? or the part that defines the `us.tx` method at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just about calling method with dot in its name, you can access that method via brackets like this:

```
client['us.tx'](args, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Calling `client.us.tx(...)` means you call method `tx` on object `us` that is property of object `client`.

Answer (score 0):

the example that you gave has an improper wsdl url. If you check the error message, you'll get the following response.

```
Error: Invalid WSDL URL: http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl

 Code: 404

 Response Body: <!doctype html>
```

So you're using it right, just calling it with a non working url

Use the following URL to see it working:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL